# Best way to use Parsley.js in Symfony

Tags: symfony, parsley.js

I'd like to use Parsley.js to form validation. What is the best way to add it to application? I've found this: https://github.com/mySportConnect/ParsleyjsServerBundle

I'm running my application on Symfony 2.0.7 (update to 2.3.* is planned).

Thanks.

Comment: You should update at least to 2.1 now

Comment: Following @Pazi comment, the composer says `"symfony/form": "~2.1"`. Which means "Symfony Form Component as of 2.1+ is required".

Comment: Yes, that's true. That's the reason why I've been asking.
Can you explain to me how ParsleyjsServerBundle works? Is it possilbe to use error messages from Symfony forms?